# Automorphisms with order 2

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

Let T be an automorphism of finite group G & order of T is 2. Taking any element in G say x then $$xT = xT^{-1} = x^{-1}T$$ which implies $x=x^{-1}$ by taking $xTT^{-1} = x^{-1}TT^{-1}$. But since not every automorphism of order 2 results $x=x^{-1}$ for all x in G (Particularly, If I consider a finite Group G with at the least one element is of order greater than 2 and defining T as $xT=x^{-1}$), The above implication is contradicting. Please help me find Where am I wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: It’s true that $xT=xT^{-1}$, but here’s the thing $xT^{-1}$ is the inverse image of $x$. Not the inverse of $xT$ as an element in $G$. So $xT^{-1}‌$ isn't necessary equal to $x^{-1}T$, however $(xT)^{-1}=x^{-1}T$. Right?

Comment: The usual notation writes functions to the left of their arguments. So, why are you using the "right-hand" notation $xT$ instead of the "left-hand" notation $Tx$?

Comment: @Ash that's nice, Now I see the difference.

Comment: @geoffrey Trang I follow it because it delivers a notion like taken an element x (first) and mapping it to something by defining map T (second) so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider a simple example. Let $G= \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}=\{0,1,2\}$. Let $T=(1,2)$, which exchanges 1 with 2 and is an automorphism of $G$ of order 2. Take $x=1$, we have $T(x)=T ^{-1} (x)=2$, but $T(x ^{-1} )=T(2)=1$.

Comment: $T$ is not an automorphism. Also, I know that strictly speaking, the elements of $G$ are equivalence classes, but it's very common to simply use $\{0,1,2\}$ and avoid the cumbersome notation.

Comment: Thanks. I've modified my answer. I think it's correct now.